# How to parse CRLF response from tcp client using socketserver?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, tcpserver, socketserver

I am writing a TCP server using python and `socketserver` and using threads. TCP server should send commands to device and read the response from the device. The device sends a initial message to server after connection and following commands are sent after processing initial message. Server is setup to handle multiple connections. The response received by the server contains CRLF `\r\n` in long string. Now, I want to parse this response and separate messages and store them. And also each starts with "$" and message length is not fixed. Example response from client:

```
b'$<MSG>\r\n$Name=TEST-Device\r\n$Ext=Test connection\r\n$Security=0\r\n$Software=xxx\r\n$Hardware=xxx\r\n$SUCCESS\r\n$<end>\r\n'
```

Next step is to parse this message and check if Name=TEST-Device (only example) and then send next commands (shown in pseudo code below).

Server code:

```
class TCPServerMultiClient:
    ...

    def handle_client(self, client_sock, client_address):

        try:
            time.sleep(5)
            print("- Waiting for initial message -")
            data = client_sock.recv(1024)
            print(data)
            while data:
                # parse the message from client
                data = data.decode('utf-8')
                i = data.rfind("\r\n")
                data, buf = data[:i + 2], data[i + 2:]
                lines = data.split("\r\n")
                lines = filter(None, lines)
                print(lines)
                for line in lines:
                    if line.startswith("$"):
                        symbol = str(line.split(",")[])
                # pseudo code! send next commands only if Name matches (from previous response)
                if Name="TEST-Deivce":

                    print("- Sending first command")
                    cmdToSend=b"first_command"
                    client_sock.sendall(cmdToSend)
                
                    time.sleep(2)            
                    print("- Recieving response")
                    data1 = client_sock.recv(1024)
                    print(data1)

                # check if client closed the connection
                data = client_sock.recv(4024)
            print(f'Connection closed by {client_address}')

        except socket.error as e:
            if e.errno == errno.ECONNABORTED:
                print(os.strerror(e.errno))
            else:
                print(str(e))
                raise

        finally:
            # close socket
            print(f'Closing client socket for {client_address}...')
            client_sock.close()
            print(f'Client socket closed for {client_address}')

    def shutdown_server(self):
        """ Shutdown the server """

        print('Shutting down server...')
        self.sock.close()
```

But I am not able to split the message and store it. Could anyone please let me know how to properly handle it? And also should I use `buffer` and `BytesIO` or `asyncio`? My goal is to have a "command queue" to send commands from server to devices and "response queue" to store all responses. Maybe I need to do it in a separate class (like Message)

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

One way to parse newline-terminated messages is to wrap the socket in a file-like object using [`socket.makefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) and use `.readline()`:

server.py:

```py
import socket
import threading

def handle(client, addr):
    print(f'{addr}: connected')
    with client, client.makefile('r', encoding='utf8') as file:
        while True:
            line = file.readline()
            if not line: break
            print(f'{addr}: {line!r}')
    print(f'{addr}: disconnected')

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('', 5000))
s.listen()
while True:
    c, a = s.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(c, a), daemon=True).start()
```

client.py

```py
import socket

def client():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('localhost', 5000))
    with s:
        s.sendall(b'$<MSG>\r\n$Name=TEST-Device\r\n$Ext=Test connection\r\n$Security=0\r\n$Software=xxx\r\n$Hardware=xxx\r\n$SUCCESS\r\n$<end>\r\n')

# demo multi-client handling
for _ in range(3):
    client()
```

Output:

```
('127.0.0.1', 2482): connected
('127.0.0.1', 2482): '$<MSG>\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2483): connected
('127.0.0.1', 2482): '$Name=TEST-Device\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2484): connected
('127.0.0.1', 2482): '$Ext=Test connection\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2483): '$<MSG>\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2482): '$Security=0\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2483): '$Name=TEST-Device\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2482): '$Software=xxx\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2483): '$Ext=Test connection\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2482): '$Hardware=xxx\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2483): '$Security=0\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2482): '$SUCCESS\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2483): '$Software=xxx\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2482): '$<end>\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2483): '$Hardware=xxx\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2484): '$<MSG>\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2483): '$SUCCESS\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2484): '$Name=TEST-Device\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2483): '$<end>\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2484): '$Ext=Test connection\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2482): disconnected
('127.0.0.1', 2484): '$Security=0\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2483): disconnected
('127.0.0.1', 2484): '$Software=xxx\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2484): '$Hardware=xxx\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2484): '$SUCCESS\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2484): '$<end>\n'
('127.0.0.1', 2484): disconnected
```